How would I place the text/div not in the center but the middle of grid lines?
In this code the item 1 is in the middle of the top row but how would I place it at the top of the column lines like at the top of the vertical line
I was trying to create a UI for binarytree when whenever i entered a left child or right child multiple items and the tree became skewed it, the root node or the parent node keeps shifting to the middle of the top row so the links to the child keep overflowing
The code is similar to this
text


.grid{
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  position: relative;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
}
.item{ 
  display: grid;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  place-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
span{
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  z-index: 100;
}
.item-1{
  grid-area: 1/1/1/-1;
}
.left_line,.right_line {
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
.left_line{
    right: 0;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    grid-area: 1/1/1/1;
}
.right_line{
    left: 0;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    grid-area: 1/2/1/2;
}
<div class='grid'>
      <div class="left_line"></div>
      <div class="right_line"></div>
  <div class='item-1 item'><span>Item-1</span></div>
  <div class='item-2 item'><span>Item-2</span></div>
  <div class='item-3 item'><span>Item-3</span></div>
</div>



